# Regex for multiline header c#

Tags: c#, regex, multiline

I'm a new c# programmer. I'm trying to make a simple c# application which will extract headers from a pdf file(book) if they are in this format :

> 1.1 THE ELECTRICAL/ELECTRONICS INDUSTRY
>
> 1.2 A BRIEF HISTORY
>
> 1.3 UNITS OF MEASUREMENT

I'm using the code:

```
string pattern = @"(\d+)(\.)(\d+) ([A-Z]+).([A-Z]+).([A-Z]+).([A-Z]+).([A-Z]+)";
Regex.match(strText,pattern);
```

which works fine for single line headers but doesn't work for two line/multiline headers. 
Can anyone help please ?

Comment: Are you talking about from the table of contents or something? You will never get regex to work if you consider the entire text of the book as a single string and run the regex once. You'll pick up many false positives and likely miss some as well.

Comment: That regular expression is not doing what you think it is doing. For example, it will match the line `XYZ1.2 A BRIEF HISTORY` and it will not match the line `2.4 SUMMARY`. I recommend you find some tutorials on regular expressions (but **do not** ask for one here as that is explicitly off topic).

Comment: Yeah I'm talking about the entire text of the book. I choose it because it was well formatted. Seems to work, but yes there are some minor problem which I think could be solved, @SledgeHammer

Comment: Yes I'm new to c#. I think I should study more. Thanks :) @AdrianHHH

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with C# style regex, but isn't a `.` an any character match (except new line)?

If you need new lines then you're going to also have to include an actual `\n`
 at the end, probably with a `?` as well unless you plan to have an alternative as well.

But I'm kind of surprised that this regex isn't causing any issues, unless the formatting of book so happens to be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have already get the required table of contents in single string and the only problem is to parse second level headers.

Regular expression modified for matching only capital letters.

You can achieve the required result with the following code:

```
    string pattern = @"((\d+\.\d+) ([A-Z\s]+)\n)+";
    var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

    var headers = new List<string>();
    for (var i = 0; i < match.Groups[1].Captures.Count; i++)
    {
        headers.Add(match.Groups[1].Captures[i].Value);
    }
```

And after it `headers` will contain all required data.

Assuming that `input` contains input data. Also, note that `\n` is new line character.

Your regex simplified.

`(\d+\.\d+)` stands for sequence of "one or more numeric character", dot, "one or more numeric character", space.

`([A-Z\s]+)\n` - "one or more capital letter or space", "new line character"

Also, read the following [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) to get familiar with C# regular expressions.

Comment: Hi thanks for the link & the solution. Your solution catches both capital & small letter strings. Is there any way to catch only the capital letters only ?

Comment: @rabinmallick I have modified regular expression in the answer for matching only captial letters and spaces